# What is the probability that a student knows the answer given that he has answered it correctly,....?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A large class in stochastic processes at at a school is taking a multiple choice test. For one particular question with m proposed multiple choice answers, the fraction of students who know the answer is p; the others will guess. The probability of answering the question correctly is 1 for the students who know the answer and 1/m for the ones who guess. What is the probability that a student knows the answer given that he has answered it correctly?

Comment: You are missing the probability of guessing the answer.

Comment: Well, if the word "guess" is used, I presume we can consider it is $1/m$. Or maybe I am extrapolating too much ?

Comment: It have multiple choice answers how we can presume 1/m?

Comment: Because there are $m$ answers for the question.

Comment: Isn't multiple choice is incoherent,or is it same as multiple choice questions,if so then you're right.

Comment: A large class in stochastic processes at at a school is taking a multiple choice test. For one particular question with m proposed multiple choice answers, the fraction of students who know the answer is p; the others will guess. The probability of answering the question correctly is 1 for the students who know the answer and 1/m for the ones who guess. What is the probability that a student knows the answer given that he has answered it correctly?

Comment: Please delete all your comments that just restate the question!

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ means "The student knows the answer" and $B$ means "The student has answered correctly", we have $P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$. If we consider that those who guess give the correct answer $1$ out of $m$ times, $P(B|A)=1$, $P(A)=p$ and $P(B)=p+(1-p)/m$.

So in the end, $P(A|B) = \frac{mp}{mp-p+1}$

Comment: A large class in stochastic processes at BUI is taking a multiple choice test. For one particular question with m proposed multiple choice answers, the fraction of students who know the answer is p; the others will guess. The probability of answering the question correctly is 1 for the students who know the answer and
1/m for the ones who guess. What is the probability that a student knows the answer given that he has answered it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

$p\left[p\left(1-n\right)+n\right]^{-1}$

Assuming that $n$ is the probably of getting the question correct for those who guess.  With reasonable assumption, $n=m^{-1}$.

Comment: A large class in stochastic processes at BUI is taking a multiple choice test. For one particular question with m proposed multiple choice answers, the fraction of students who know the answer is p; the others will guess. The probability of answering the question correctly is 1 for the students who know the answer and 1/m for the ones who guess. What is the probability that a student knows the answer given that he has answered it correctly?

Comment: @Hassan, your question has already been answered twice.