# Likelihood of knowing the answer given y correct answers on multiple choice test

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution, bayes-theorem, maximum-likelihood

I've been trying to solve the following problem but am thrown off by the "guessing in case she doesn't know the answer". The problem is as follows:

> A student takes a test with n questions of equal difficulty. For each question, the student has a
> probability $\theta$ of knowing the answer and in that case she solves the question perfectly. If she does
> not know the answer, she guesses and then she has a probability of 0.5 of solving it correctly. The
> responses to all n questions can be considered independent.

Based on this information, the following is asked:

> Derive analytically the likelihood function for $\theta$ given y correctly solved items.

The "likelihood given y correctly solved items" confuses me. I've seen many examples of solving $P(\theta|Y=1)$ using Bayes' theorem (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680858/what-is-the-probability-that-a-student-knows-the-answer-given-that-he-has-answer)). But how can this be generalized to a likelihood for $\theta$ given y correctly solved items? Do we even need Bayes' theorem or can this just be answered with a Binomial distribution *corrected* for the guessing given she doesn't know the answer?

Furthermore, a follow-up question is asked:

> Assuming a beta prior with constants a and b, derive an expression for the marginal probability
> $p(y)$. Simplify the expression, but leave the integral if there is no closed-form solution.

This makes me believe Bayes' theorem would indeed be used for the first question.
Any help on any part of this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I confirm that the required likelihood function $L(\theta\mid Y=y) = P(Y=y\mid \theta)$, as defined in [likelihood function on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function)?

Comment: The phrasing is a bit awkward in my opinion. Usually I wouldnt say "likelihood given $Y$" since "given" implies that you are conditioning on $Y$, but that is not typically how the likelihood is defined. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood of $\theta$ is $\mathbb P(Y=y | \theta)$ (the probability of the data given the parameter). But $Y$ is just a binomial random variable given $\theta$, where the success probability is given by the probability of getting a question correct. So all we need to do is calculate the probability of getting any one question correct.

$$p_\theta:=\mathbb P (\text{correct}) = \mathbb P(\text{correct} | \text{known})\mathbb P(\text{known}) + \mathbb P(\text{correct} | \text{unknown})\mathbb P(\text{unknown}) = \theta + (1-\theta)\cdot0.5$$

Then the likelihood is:
$$\sum_i^n \binom{n}{i}{p_\theta}^i(1-p_\theta)^{n-i}$$